# Name for hypergeometric-like sum.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, special-functions

Consider the sum

$F(a_1,\cdots,a_r; z)\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a_1+m)(a_2+m)\cdots(a_r+m)}{(a_1)(a_2)\cdots (a_r)}\frac{z^m}{m!},$

where $a_i$ for $i=1,2,\cdots,r$ is an increasing sequence of positive integers. And yes the denominator is independendent of $m$.
 In some cases the ratio becomes hypergeometric when restricting the sum over a particular set of indices. Surely such functions have been studied before? Do they have a common name? Is there a nice integral representation?

Comment: Is the denominator of the coefficient independent on $m$? Actually any series for which the ratio of consecutive coefficients is a rational function of $m$ is a generalized hypergeometric function. Your series definitely falls into this class.

Comment: @O.L. Correct. I did this to emphasize for example if $a_i=i$, then the fraction becomes something like $(r)_m$

Comment: @O.L.: It's true, if I fill in all the gaps I'll get some ${}_mF_n$ function but I was hoping for something slightly simpler.

Comment: But it seems you have something much simpler. Denote $P(m)=\frac{(a_1+m) \ldots (a_r+m)}{a_1 \ldots a_r}$. Then $F$ is equal to $P(\delta) e^z$, where $\delta =z\partial_z$.

Comment: @O.L. That's really cute. Is there some theory about these kinds of expressions? For example is there a nice integral representation?

Comment: $\delta$'s are used all the time in the theory of hypergeometric functions, but I don't know if $P(\delta)e^z$ gives rise to some known special polynomials or something like that.